# Connecting .net Micro framework console application emulator to Azure Service Bus

Tags: amqp, azureservicebus, .net-micro-framework, azure-servicebus-queues

I am novice to NETMF and trying to build a console application which send a message to a Queue on windows Azure Service Bus. I am also using AMQP protocol to connect. But every time I get below error.

> Exception thrown: 'Amqp.AmqpException' in Amqp.NetMF.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'Amqp.AmqpException' occurred in
>   Amqp.NetMF.dll
>
> Additional information: The connection was inactive for more than the
>   allowed 60000 milliseconds and is closed by container 'LinkTracker'.
>   TrackingId:aeed7786111b4e28b08d9f07292843e0_G19,
>   SystemTracker:gateway6, Timestamp:1/18/2017 7:23:15 AM

Now, I suspect that this is due to that Sample Emulator, which comes with Visual Studio, is not able to access the internet of my laptop.

I also read that I would need a Netduino board for this. Is it true?

Is there any way I can connect to Azure Service Bus while I debug .net micro framework console application on my laptop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is returned when you open a connection but not any links within 60 seconds. Your application has connected to the Service Bus service. It did not create a link probably because you were debugging the application.

There was an issue in the Sample Emulator with SSL connections. The issue was fixed but last time I checked it was not in the 4.4 release. You can find more details here.
https://github.com/NETMF/netmf-interpreter/issues/330

https://github.com/NETMF/netmf-interpreter/pull/342

Comment: A Big Thanks to you Xin, I spend almost whole day finding the cause of this error....above links will sure help me....